# Erro ao instalar npm no Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: laravel-5, token-ajax

Estou no início do aprendizado do laravel junto com ajax e não estou conseguindo passar dados via post com ajax.

Este é meu ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', "#cad_academia", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //var data = $("#new_gym").serialize();
    var cnpj     = $("#cnpj").val();
    var academia = $("#academia").val();
    var telefone = $("#telefone").val();
    var email    = $("#email").val();

    var data = {
        "cnpj" : cnpj,
        "academia" : academia,
        "telefone" : telefone,
        "email" : email
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'adicionar_academia',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {data: data},
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        method: 'post'
    }).done(function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    });
})
```

e este é o controller:

```
public function create(Request $data) {
        $academia = $data->academia;
        $telefone = $data->telefone;
        $email    = $data->email;
        $cnpj     = $data->cnpj;
        $status   = 3;
        $plano    = rand(0,2);

        // Faz a verificação no banco se já existe o e-mail cadastrado
        $verifica_email = DB::table('academias')->where('email', $email)->get();
        $verifica_cnpj  = DB::table('academias')->where('cnpj', $cnpj)->get();
        $msg = '';
        if(count($verifica_email) > 0) {
            $msg = 'O e-mail informado já existe na nossa base de dados. Favor, escolher outro e-mail para efetuar o cadastro';
            return view('criar', compact('msg'));

        } else if(count($verifica_cnpj) > 0){
            $msg = 'O cnpj informado já existe na nossa base de dados. Favor, escolher outro cnpj para efetuar o cadastro';
            return view('criar', compact('msg'));
        } else {
            $dados =
            [
                'academia'  => $academia,
                'email'     => $email,
                'telefone'  => $telefone,
                'status'    => $status,
                'cnpj'      => $cnpj,
                'plano'     => $plano,
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d')
            ];

            DB::table('academias')->insert($dados);
            $msg = 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso!';
            return view('criar', compact('msg'));
        }
    }
```

Li, até mesmo aqui no stackoverflow de que é necessário passar o csrf nos headers da requisição ajax mas mesmo passando não consigo obter o resultado esperado. Aparece o código 419.

Comment: Erro? Se sim, diga qual pff

Comment: Como mencionei, ele retorna o código 419 não concluindo a requisição post via ajax. Get vai normal, apenas no post que não estou conseguindo ter o mesmo resultado mesmo passado o token na chamada ajax.

Comment: Talvez esta solução ajude, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46493409/3162303